# Behaviour of modified Bessel function of the second kind $K_{\nu}(x)$

Tags: complex-analysis, asymptotics, bessel-functions

The modified Bessel function of the second kind $K_{\nu} (x)$ should have an exponential - decreasing - behaviour with respect to its variable $x$, as shown in [this document](http://www.mhtlab.uwaterloo.ca/courses/me755/web_chap4.pdf) (page 19, fig. 4.4).

As stated [here](http://math.arizona.edu/~zakharov/BesselFunctions.pdf) (page 14), the Bessel functions $J_{\nu}(iz)$ and $N_{\nu}(iz)$ of the first and the second kind with a complex argument $iz$ have the following asymptotic behaviour

$$J_{\nu}(iz) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi iz}} \cos \left( iz - \frac{\nu \pi}{2} - \frac{\pi}{4} \right)$$
$$N_{\nu}(iz) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi iz}} \sin \left( iz - \frac{\nu \pi}{2} - \frac{\pi}{4} \right)$$

How to prove from them that $K_{\nu} (x)$ has an exponential behaviour? "Google" provides so many definitions of $K_{\nu} (x)$, but not this proof.

Comment: From which definition are you interested in obtaining the asymptotic?

Comment: It is sufficient to note that $$K_{\nu}(x) = \frac{\pi}{2}i^{\nu + 1}(J_{\nu}(ix) + i N_{\nu}(ix)).$$With this it follows that for $x\rightarrow\infty$, $$K_{\nu}(x) = \frac{\pi}{2}i^{\nu + 1}\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi ix}}\Big[\cos \big(ix+\alpha\big)+i \sin \big(ix + \alpha\big)\Big]$$ where $\alpha$ is the phase shift. Now if one uses the definition of $\cos(\theta)$ and $\sin(\theta)$ in terms of exponentials and the above final form, it is easy to see that indeed $K_{\nu}$ falls off exponentially.

Comment: @AntonioVargas "How to prove from them that...": I was referring to the asymptotic definition (showed in the question) of $J_{\nu}(iz)$ and $N_{\nu}(iz)$.

Comment: @vnd Thank you, I didn't have clear the definition of $K_{\nu}(x)$. $\alpha$ should be $- \nu \frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{\pi}{4}$ and my result is $$K_{\nu}(x) = \frac{\pi}{2} \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi x}} e^{-x}$$ Can you confirm that? If you want, you can post an answer!

Comment: @BowPark Yes, apart from constant factors, $K_{\nu}(x) \sim \frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt x}. $

Comment: @vnd, you should make your comment into an answer :)

Comment: @AntonioVargas Done. I think it is alright to leave the previous comments as they were.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The modified Bessel Function of the second kind $K_{\nu}(x)$ may be expressed as $$K_{\nu}(x) = \frac{\pi}{2}i^{\nu + 1}(J_{\nu}(ix) + i N_{\nu}(ix))$$ With this it follows that for $x\rightarrow\infty$ $$K_{\nu}(x) \sim  \frac{\pi}{2}i^{\nu + 1}\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi ix}}\Big[\cos \big(ix+\alpha\big)+i \sin \big(ix + \alpha\big)\Big]$$ $$\implies K_{\nu}(x)\sim \frac{\exp (-x)}{\sqrt x}$$ by Euler's formula.

Comment: Sorry but why does $\nu$ disapear in this formula ?

Comment: It doesn't disappear, its just that one wants to show the dependence of $K_{\nu}(x)$ on $x$. The last implication is only upto some factor.

Comment: @vnd, It does disappear, unless I'm missing something. Express $e^{i\alpha}=\left(-i\right)^\nu\sqrt{-i}$ and all the factors involving $i$ cancel.